# Is there a way to put quotes in a cout?

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a simple calculator and I would like to display quotes in the instruction when you first run the program.

Comment: I assume you've just started with C++? I feel this question is more suited for Google than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Use `\"`. Also known as [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use raw strings:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << R"_(A raw string with " inside (and \ as well))_" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cad51755a66ec1b9)

Output:

> A raw string with " inside (and \ as well)

---

#### Quotes from the Standard:

According to the Standard 2.14.5 [lex.string]:

```
string-literal:
    encoding-prefixopt "s-char-sequenceopt"
    encoding-prefixopt R raw-string

encoding-prefix:
    u8
    u
    U
    L

s-char-sequence:
    s-char
    s-char-sequence s-char

s-char:
    any member of the source character set except
        the double-quote ", backslash \, or new-line character
    escape-sequence
    universal-character-name

raw-string:
    " d-char-sequenceopt ( r-char-sequenceopt) d-char-sequenceopt "

r-char-sequence:
    r-char
    r-char-sequence r-char

r-char:
    any member of the source character set, except
        a right parenthesis ) followed by the initial d-char-sequence
        (which may be empty) followed by a double quote ".

d-char-sequence:
    d-char
    d-char-sequence d-char

d-char:
    any member of the basic source character set except:
        space, the left parenthesis (, the right parenthesis ), the backslash \,
        and the control characters representing horizontal tab,
        vertical tab, form feed, and newline.
```

> 1. A string literal is a sequence of characters (as defined in 2.14.3) surrounded by double quotes, optionally prefixed by `R`, `u8`, `u8R`,
>      `u`, `uR`, `U`, `UR`, `L`, or `LR`, as in `"..."`, `R"(...)"`,
>      `u8"..."`, `u8R"**(...)**"`, `u"..."`, `uR"*˜(...)*˜"`, `U"..."`,
>      `UR"zzz(...)zzz"`, `L"..."`, or `LR"(...)"`, respectively.
> 2. A string literal that has an `R` in the prefix is a *raw string literal*. The `d-char-sequence` serves as a delimiter. The terminating
>      `d-char-sequence` of a raw-string is the same sequence of characters
>      as the initial `d-char-sequence`. A `d-char-sequence` shall consist of
>      at most 16 characters.
> 3. [Note: The characters `(` and `)` are permitted in a raw-string. Thus, `R"delimiter((a|b))delimiter"` is equivalent to `"(a|b)"`. —end
>      note ]
> 4. [Note: A source-file new-line in a raw string literal results in a new-line in the resulting execution `string-literal`. Assuming no
>      whitespace at the beginning of lines in the following example, the
>      assert will succeed:
>
>    ```
>    const char *p = R"(a\
>    b
>    c)";
>    assert(std::strcmp(p, "a\\\nb\nc") == 0);
>    ```
>
>    — end note ]
> 5. [Example: The raw string
>
>    ```
>    R"a(
>    )\
>    a"
>    )a"
>    ```
>
>    is equivalent to `"\n)\\\na\"\n"`. The raw string
>
>    ```
>    R"(??)"
>    ```
>
>    is equivalent to `"\?\?"`. The raw string
>
>    ```
>    R"#(
>    )??="
>    )#"
>    ```
>
>    is equivalent to `"\n)\?\?=\"\n"`. —end example ]

Comment: I learned a thing. Thanks :)

Comment: I was thinking about that, maybe a bit overkilling for a double quote, but I love it!! Upvoted.

Comment: @swinefish, this is the main purpose of SO. You are always welcome :)